# How to add a custom Property as a child of a PropertyGroup in MSBuild?

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-propertygroup

I have the following build script, which I run with MSBuild:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Compile" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion ="3.5">
<PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDir Condition=" '$(BuildDir)'==' ' ">$(BaseDir)/build</BuildDir>
    <ProdDir >$(BuildDir)/prod</ProdDir>
    <TestDir>$(BuildDir)/test</TestDir>
    <MMC2SourceDir>SteuerungsZugriffTest/mmc2</MMC2SourceDir>
    <UserSourceDir>SteuerungsZugriffTest/user</UserSourceDir>
    <TestXMLDir>$(BuildDir)/test-results</TestXMLDir>
    <SolutionFile Condition=" '$(SolutionFile)'==' ' ">HMI2.0.sln</SolutionFile>"
    <NUnitTest>nunit-console.exe</NUnitTest>
</PropertyGroup>
<Target Name="Prepare">
    <Message Text="Prepare everything" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(BuildDir)" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(ProdDir)" />
</Target>
...
```

When I now start script on the command line:

```
D:\MyDir>msbuild /property:BaseDir=D:\MyDir MyScript.build
```

I got the following error on the commandline output:

```
D:\MyDir>MyScript.build(11,78): error MSB4067: Das <#text>-Element unterhalb des <PropertyGroup>-Elements ist unbekannt.
```

Which basically means: *The element<#text> is an unknown child*.

Does anybody have an idea?

Edit: Sorry, I completed now the script

Comment: Looks OK at first glance - the error is at line 11 character 78 which I don't think you have included. Can you post more of your script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra " at the end of this line

```
<SolutionFile Condition=" '$(SolutionFile)'==' ' ">HMI2.0.sln</SolutionFile>"
```

It is outside a tag, so it is considered as a text element...